# How to separate table rows with space between them without border-spacing?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

I'm trying to do `margin-bottom` in my table to separate the table rows and it does not do anything.
So, I tried with `flex` and it works but the table row does not inherit the width, and I must put specific width.
Is there other way to separate the table rows?

This is the code with `flex`:

```
<table className="w-full text-sm text-left lg:table-fixed table-fixed">
      <thead className="text-sm text-white text-opacity-50 font-normal ">
       ...
      </thead>

      {() => (
        <tbody className={classNames({ ' text-white text-sm   flex flex-col': true })}>
          {dataT.map(vt => {
            return <VaultTransactionsRow key={vt.id} {...vt} />
          })}
        </tbody>
      )}
    </table>
```

[This is the table that I created with flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAEUh.png)

[This is the table that I created with no affect of margin-bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unumj.png)

Comment: It's not the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

use `border-collapse:seprate` with `border-spacing` to add spacing.

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
```

Comment: HI, it does not work for me, it make a little space between the ```tr``` and the ```td```, but if I increase the spacing nothing happened .